# Animation in svg.js dont have same result

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

My code of svg.js use rotate action and move action, but two results dont have the same center coordinate
Here is my code

```html
<body>
    <div id="drawing"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.6/svg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var draw = SVG('drawing')
        var group_1 = draw.group()
        var group_2 = draw.group()
        var rect_1 = group_1.rect(50, 20).fill('#f06').center(50, 50)
        var rect_2 = group_2.rect(50, 20).fill('#f09').center(50, 50)

        rect_1.animate(1000).rotate(45).after(function(){    
        group_1.animate(1000).center(100, 100)})

        group_2.animate(1000).center(100, 100)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is your question / issue ?

Comment: I think the center of two rects have to be the same, but it is not

Answer (score 0):

In SVG groups needs to be understood as a grouping of elements. Basically the same as in photohop. You can select multiple elements and rotate or scale them at once.
That in turn means that groups do not have geometry on its own. It fully depends on the content where the group is visible on the screen (x, y) or how bif it is (with/height).

Thats the reason, why you cannot `move` a group. You only can transform it. To keep the api simple, svg.js gives you the handy move and center method which - under the hood - translate the group.

In your example, you move the group after you rotated it. But you do it with an absolute transformation. That means svg.js tries to incooperate the movement into the already present rotation. This maths does not goes off well sometimes.

To fix your problem you have to use relative transformations instead.
Which means the movement is ON TOP of the rotation. That also means that you have to figure out by how much you wanna move the group.

We are currently working on version 3 of svg.js which simplifies this transformation business alot. So I hope the final solution will be there soon